# java gwt celltree

Tags: java, gwt, tree

I implemented a CellTree structure in java gwt which opens it's childs when clicking on the little arrow in the cell contains. Is it possible to open the subtree also when just clicking on the cell itself and not explicitly on the arrow?

```
public class SomeCellTree extends Composite {


    private SelectionModel selectionModel;
    private CellTree cellTree;



    private class SomeTreeViewModel implements TreeViewModel {
         @Override
         public <T> NodeInfo<?> getNodeInfo(T value) {
             ...
         }

         @Override
         public boolean isLeaf(Object value) {
             ...
         }  
    }



    public SomeCellTree(...) {

       this.selectionModel = new SingleSelectionModel();
       this.selectionModel.addSelectionChangeHandler(new SelectionChangeEvent.Handler() {
           @Override
           public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event) {
                         ...
           }
       });

       cellTree = new CellTree(new SomeTreeViewModel(),null,RESOURCES);
       initWidget(cellTree);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use recursion to find the node for the selected DTO and then you have to call `setChildOpen` to open the subtree. Something like this:

```
this.selectionModel.addSelectionChangeHandler(new SelectionChangeEvent.Handler() {
    @Override
    public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event) {
         T selectedObj = selectionModel.getSelectedObject();
         TreeNode rootNode = cellTree.getRootTreeNode();
         openTree(rootNode,T);
    }
});


private void openTree(rootNode node,T object) {
    for (int i = 0; i < node.getChildCount(); i++) {
        if (!node.isChildLeaf(i)) {
            find(node.setChildOpen(i, true));
            if (node.getValue().equals(T)) 
                return;
        }
    }
}
```